# Beginner 'Guess my number' program. while loop not breaking when correct number guessed or when out of guesses

Tags: python

So I'm learning python and I'm trying to code a simple guess my number game where you only have 5 guesses or the game ends. Im really having trouble with the while loop not recognising that the number has been guessed or the  guess limit has been reached. Is there a better way of formatting my functions also. Thanks for any and all help, first time using this site.

```
# Guess my number
#
# The computer picks a random number between 1 and 100
# The player tries to guess it and the computer lets
# the player know if the guess is too high, too low
# or right on the money

import random

GUESS_LIMIT = 5

# functions
def display_instruct():
    """Display game instructions."""
    print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!")
    print("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
    print("Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.")
    print("\nHARDCORE mode - You have 5 tries to guess the number!\n")


def ask_number(question, low, high, step = 1):
    """Ask for a number within a range."""
    response = None
    while response not in range(low, high, step):
        response = int(input(question))
    return response


def guessing_loop():
    the_number = random.randint(1, 100)
    guess = ask_number("\nTake a guess:", 1, 100)
    tries = 1

    while guess != the_number or tries != GUESS_LIMIT:
        if guess > the_number:
            print("Lower...")
        else:
            print("Higher...")

        guess = ask_number("Take a guess:", 1, 100)
        tries += 1

    if tries == GUESS_LIMIT:
        print("\nOh no! You have run out of tries!")
        print("Better luck next time!")
    else:
        print("\nYou guessed it! The number was", the_number)
        print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!")


def main():
    display_instruct()
    guessing_loop()


# start the program
main()
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

Comment: Your `or` needs to be an `and`.

Answer (score 2):

Your while condition will be true as long as you haven't hit the guess limit.

```
while guess != the_number or tries != GUESS_LIMIT:
```

You should join those conditions with `and`, not `or`.  The way you have it now, the entire condition will be true because `tries != GUESS_LIMIT` is true, even if `guess != the_number` is false.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can break your cycle explicitly with `break` statement. But previous answer is more correct in a sense you should really understand conditions you're setting for the loop.